# Foliage wind effect with hair particles + turbulence

Tags: particles, hair

I've been working on this scene trying to create a smooth wind effect using hair particles + turbulence effector.

[GIF HERE](https://gfycat.com/rectangularevergreenindianpangolin)

[image: Frame 1]

I've tried a lot of different settings but there's always some individual plants rotating on a weird way, it breaks the smoothness of the effect.

How can I achive this? is it possible with geometry nodes?
This is how I'm trying to do it:

Create a plane, subdivide it, weight painted desired area for the plants, create a particle system, change it to hair, set render as object, select instance object (plant), add turbulence effector, animate it, play with the settings.

I'm not sure if I need to add a constraint to the original object or my turbulence settings are not good.

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Turbulence is not like wind, really. Maybe try a wind field, but set it to the “apbsorbed by objects” thingy? That would be most realistic. If all else fails, use an animated wave texture instead to entirely fake the motion.